# Use Output as Input

Tags: output-formatting

I have this function which as a result returns a point

```
f[x, y] = 
  Max[((x - #[[1]])^2 + (y - #[[2]])^2) & /@ Subscript[Rp, A0]];
min = Minimize[{f[x, y], {20 <= x <= 80, 20 <= y <= 80}}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {576.25, {x -> 34.5, y -> 52.}}
> ```

How can I use this point $(x,y)$ as an input ?

Comment: If you set `sol = Minimize[...]` then use `sol[[2, All, 2]]`.

Comment: or `{x, y}/. Last@sol`, More in [Common pitfalls awaiting new users](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/5478).